# Issues creating an object using data from 3 other objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a javascript function that builds a round-robin for a badminton tournament.  The problem is players are being added or dropping out half-way in the tournament, forcing the round robin to recalculate itself and matching players that have already played.

I'm trying to rewrite the logic to the following:

1. Find the player that played the least amount of games
2. Find an opponent that the player played the least amount of games against
3. Match them up
4. Stop if the player or opponent has reach 10 games

I have been working on this for days and still can't get this to function properly.

I have 4 objects:

- `allPlayers`
- `playersAvailable`
- `gamesCompleted`
- `gamesScheduled`

The `gamesScheduled` object is created from the data of the other 3 objects and gets recalculated when a new player is added or removed.

```
allplayers: [{.key: -playerKey, name: 'Name'}]

playersAvailable: [{.key:-playerKey, name: 'Name'}]

gamesCompleted: [{playerKey: {opponentKey:numberOfGames,opponentKey:numberOfGames}]
```

The `gamesCompleted` object does not contain all players.

**I'm having trouble generating the `gamesScheduled` object (javascript/es6).  Here's my approach so far:**

1. Sort `playersAvailable` by least amount of games played
2. Loop through `playersAvailable`, if they haven't played 10 games, look for opponents they haven't played yet by comparing the `gamesCompleted` list with the `playersAvailable` list, if the opponent doesn't have 10 games played, create a matchup.
3. Loop through `playersAvailable`, if they haven't played 10 games, look for opponents they have played the least amount of times in the `gamesCompleted` list, if the opponent doesn't have 10 games played, create a matchup.

I can get as far as #1 & partly #2., but when verifying the number of games played (max:10) I can't figure out how to include the newly added games within the `gamesScheduled` object.

Partial Code, when looping through opponents with `forEach()`

```
var gamesScheduled = [];
  let playersAvailable = this.weekPlayers.slice().sort((a, b) => {
    let aTotal = a.gs + a.gp;
    let bTotal = b.gs + b.gp;
    return aTotal - bTotal;
  });

  playersAvailable.forEach((player) => {
    // if missing games
    if (player.gp < 10) {
      playerAvailable.forEach(opponent => {

        // add opponents unplayed
        if (
          gamesPlayed[player[".key"]] &&
          gamesPlayed[player[".key"]][opponent[".key"]] === undefined &&
          opponent.gp <10
        ) {
          gamesScheduled.push({ player1: player, player2: opponent });

        }

        // add opponents played

      });
    }
  });
  return gamesScheduled;
```

Comment: It'll also get VTC'd for asking for "resources" which usually means off-site stuff.  Can you show whatever the last code you tried was, at least, that'd help folks help you.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly, that you are stuck when the person in question has already played everyone, but you now want to put them with the person they have played least?  Are there people that they have not played, but they are already playing somebody else, so you just need to wait until they are done?  I don't think I am understanding your question at the end.

Comment: I'm stuck at including the gamesScheduled object, which is the object this script is creating, in the calculation of games played.

Comment: i.e. if (Games Completed + Games Scheduled < 10) add a matchup to gamesScheduled.

Comment: Thanks Paul I edited the question and included my code so far